# Understanding mathematical representation of SINR

Tags: digital-communications, snr, fading-channel

I am getting confused in SINR for the following received signal expression.

$$y(n) = (h+fg)s(n) + w(n) \tag{1}$$

Where $h,f,g$ are zero mean circularly symmetric Complex Gaussian (ZMCSCG) channels. All these channels are independent in nature with variance $\sigma^2_a$. $s(n)$ is transmitted signal and is also ZMCSCG with variance $P_s$, $w(n)$ is AWGN with Variance $N_w$.

Note that out of these 3 channels,$f$ is desired channel and $h$ is interference channel.

The SINR from (1) can be expressed as

$$\gamma = \frac{|f|^2\sigma^2_aP_s}{\sigma^2_aP_s +N_w} \tag{2}$$

Where $\sigma^2_a$ in Numerator corresponds to $g$ and $\sigma^2_a$ in denominator corresponds to $h$.

My query is why in (2) $\sigma^2_a$ is taken, whereas in case of $f$ its magnitude square i.e. $|f|^2$ is considered.

Comment: Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The reason may be that while $f$, $g$, and $h$ are all random, $f$ is the only one to be known (e.g. by sounding techniques).

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. Can you please clarify what do you mean by sounding techniques?

Comment: @paru hm, could you explain why it's strange to use the magnitude square of the scale (which is the standard deviation $\sigma_a$, so it's square is $\sigma_a^2$) when looking for a power? This looks all pretty intuitive to me: The numerator is simply $E\left(\left\lvert fgs(n) \right\rvert^2\right)$, written down directly from the definition of these three variables.

Comment: oh wait, that's not correct: if $f, g, s$ are all independent central normal, then $fg$ already follows a product distribution with variance $\sigma_a^4$, and $(fg)s$ hence has a variance of $\sigma_a^4 P_s$. Are you sure that formula $(2)$ is correct?

Comment: Sir, I am not sure about Formula (2), I had written it as per my understanding.  I also got your point i.e., $(fg)s$ has variance of $\sigma^4_aP_s$. But this is where I am getting confused. In some cases variance of channel (which is a random variable) is written as magnitude square and in some cases as $\sigma^2$. So which approach is correct one?

Comment: variance is always a real number, so there's no difference?

Comment: Sir, but I think both are different. Let us consider that channel $h$ is ZMCSCG with unit variance. In that case if we write $|h|^2$ then it becomes exponential random variable whereas if we write $\sigma^2$ then it will be 1. Is my understanding correct sir?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying there. You're comparing a random variable $Y$, $Y=|h|^2$, with a constant, $\sigma^2$. Is it possible you're forgetting e.g. an expectation operator somewhere?

Comment: No sir not forgetting expectation operator.

Comment: By "sounding techniques" I meant sending known sequences to estimate $f$. In Eq. (1) $f, g, h$ do not depend on time $n$ suggesting that they are (quasi)-static random variables and, therefore, can be estimated. As $f$ is known, the SINR should be $\gamma = \frac{|f|^2\sigma^2_aP_s + \sigma^2_aP_s}{N_w} $

Comment: ... because the "signal" part is $(h+fg)s(n)$. Note that which part is "signal" depends on how your receiver is designed. Specifically, (2) makes sense only if your receiver is able to distinguish $fg \times s(n)$ from $h \times s(n)$ in $y(n)$.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense, @AlexTP